# Sorting images (so they are viewable in windows' file explorer) by content similarity

Tags: file-management, images, image-processing, file-search

I've been able to find a lot of similar questions, most on photos stackexchange, but I couldn't find any satisfactory answers.

What I AM looking for:

Sort/Rename images based on the similarity of the contents of the image, through a desktop app (or python script or similar). Ideally open source, and MUST work on Windows 10.

What I AM NOT looking for:

Show images that are similar, for the purpose of deleting duplicates (Something like dupeGuru)

Sort or show images that are similar/duplicates based on EXIF data, file names, etc.

Sort or show images that are similar by content, through a web interface/website that requires uploading.

Sort/Delete/Show images that are identical based off the file content (through a sha1 hash or something similar)

Some questions I've come across:

https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10574/ive-lost-a-photo-i-know-i-have-it-but-i-dont-know-where-how-can-i-find-it
This suggests [imgseek](http://www.imgseek.net/), however it's interface is old, clunky, and generally hard to use and figure out. It also suggests [Imense Desktop Similar Image Search](http://www.imense.com/similarsearch/desktop), however this link returns a 404 error.

https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14094/is-there-a-free-visual-similarity-image-local-hard-drive-search
Suggests imgseek, [DigiKam](https://www.digikam.org/drupal/node/321) (404 error), and [pixcavator](https://inperc.com/wiki/index.php?title=Pixcavator_image_search) (404 error)

https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/69226/how-can-i-sort-pictures-in-a-folder-based-on-similarity

I couldn't find any real answers for this question, although the OP seems to be asking for what I want.

I want to say again that I am NOT looking for something that is intended to help delete/remove/show duplicates, like dupeGuru's image functionality.

If there is something I should make more clear, or otherwise change, please, let me know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are many metrics for image similarity. The one most frequently implemented is to resample the image down to a small number of pixels and use the proportion of identical pixels as the similarity metric. Usually this metric is used by de-dupe programs but it is not generally made accessible to other programs. If it was, it could be used for the purpose you describe, but which image comes first in the sort is not clear. Most de-dup programs use a date metadata for this purpose. I'm not aware of any programs that make similarity data available externally but maybe someone else is!